# How to customize the Lead Conversion Standard Email Notifications?

Tags: email, email-template, lead-conversion, email-alert

I am trying to customize the Lead Conversion Email notification. This notification is enabled through checking the "Send Email to the Owner" checkbox (*plesase refer to the screenshot*), at the conversion moment.

I checked te Standard Email templates, from setup, but I can't find any option relevant to this.

Any help is appreciated.[image]

Thanks,
Endrit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't change that email notification template.

Here is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpQgAAK) for the same.

**Workaround**:

Users should avoid clicking the checkbox "Send Email to the Owner" when they convert a Lead.

You can create a Workflow to send an Email Alert when Lead gets converted.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Any reference to the standard documentation would help though.

Comment: @EndritSino I was looking to get Salesforce Doc link, but could not able to find it.